# How can I multiplicate double numbers correctly?

Tags: powershell

I have the problem, that I can't multiplicate two numbers in PowerShell. The point is somehow ignored and my factor `1.5` is raised to `15`. So the result is 10 times bigger than it is supposed to be (`720` vs. `7200`).

```
$factor = 1.5

$ret = 0
$ret = [double]::Parse(480) * [double]::Parse($factor);

Write-Host $ret      # result 7200 instead of 720
```

I tried casts with `double`,`decimal`,`int` at any place, but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Wait a sec, `$ret = 0` so ret is an int at first ? I'am not a pro for sure, but couldn't it be a problem when you assign a double right after that ?

Comment: Whatfor do you need `::parse()`? Remove that! `$ret = [double]480 * [double]$factor` should be enough.

Comment: @xoxel No even if I remove `$ret = 0` the result is the same

Comment: Okay, good to know !

Comment: @Olaf your method is working. And my Parse is probably redundant, but in theory its supposed to work anyway, isnt it? I assumed factor to be string which is wrong... how does he get to 15?

Comment: What happens when you do `[double]::Parse($factor)` ? I don't know what the `::parse()` method is good for and where do you get that, but it does not help you in your case.  ;-)

Comment: `Write-Host ([double]::Parse($factor))` delivers `15`. And it doesnt matter if I use `$factor = "1.5"` or `$factor = 1.5`. Does powershell internally parse to double data type or how can 1.5 become 15

Comment: I consider myself more as a DevOps man than a developer. ;-) So I don't know why. But you might get some more information from the documentation [Double.Parse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx)